# How do I select data from a table int MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I have a table in MATLAB, its data types are a mixture of cell-strings and cells.
one of the table columns is 'Laterality' and the data is a cell-string.

I want to select all the data with Laterality = 'L'

So I do:

```
newTable = (table.Laterality == 'L')
```

as per the documentation: https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/tables.html

However this gives the error:

```
Undefined function 'eq' for input arguments of type 'cell'.
```

I've tried changing the  data type to chars. I've tried using the dataset type instead of the table. Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With [cellfun](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cellfun.html) function:

```
eq_L = cellfun(@(lat) strcmp(lat, 'L'), your_table.Laterality);
               % each cell content (named lat) is compared(*) with 'L'
```

or as recalled by @excaza, `strcmp()` can handle cell arrays:

```
eq_L = strcmp(your_table.Laterality, 'L');
```

Then

```
newTable = your_table(eq_L,:); % logical indexing
```

`eq_L` is an array of same size with logical values used for [logical indexing](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/matrix-indexing.html).

<sup>(*)</sup> If every cell is only 1 character, then you could write `lat == 'L'`. But if some are more than 1 character (or empty), then you'll get an error comparing arrays of different sizes. `strcmp()` can handle both cases.

Comment: Brilliant thank you very much!
Just for reference I ended up having to do `newTable = your_table(eq_L,:);` as the the last line to get all the data in the new table

Comment: `strcmp` works on cell arrays natively, there's no reason to use `cellfun` and slow down the operation.